# how to connect IBM cloudant database to local python code?

Tags: python-3.x, nosql, ibm-cloud, cloudant, dbconnection

```py
from cloudant.client import Cloudant
from cloudant.error import CloudantException
from cloudant.result import Result, ResultByKey

client = Cloudant("23000-xxx-yyy-0000-b9111111b-bluemix", 
    "axx483d9xxxxxxxxx290ab34xx7a5421b3500f6c0002acfd", 
    url="https://23000-xxx-yyy-0000-b9111111b-bluemix:axx483d9xxxxxxxxx290ab34xx7a5421b3500f6c0002acfd@2374770e-6e45-45a7-91ba-b9214865a81b-bluemix.cloudantnosqldb.appdomain.cloud")

client.connect()

database_name = "Translation_DB"

my_database = client.create_database(database_name)
```

this code is not connecting to the cloud database
I am trying to connect from my local pc to the db in cloud

Comment: what error code do you get?

Comment: Where did you get the credentials from? Is this a public endpoint?

Comment: no error code is there  ; That connection object is blank it is not getting anything in return;   I am following this link -- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-getting-started-with-cloudant

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the non-creation of the database in Cloudant NoSQL DB service on IBM Cloud is the *Cloudant database name*. If you read the note carefully, only lower characters are allowed in the database name.

> The database name must begin with a letter and can include only
>   lowercase characters (a-z), numerals (0-9), and any of the following
>   characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and /.

Using `translation_db` as the database_name should work as expected.

To see the success message in the output, add the below code snippet

```
if my_database.exists():
    print(f"'{database_name}' successfully created.")
```